# How do I detect whether MySQL is installed?

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, windows

Without the help of the registry, how do I know whether MySQL is installed or not? I am trying to determine this on a Windows machine through C#.

I have found a solution that involves querying the registry, but I don't want to rely on this. Is there any function in C# for determining the currently installed software?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: @Matten: Should be clearer now...

Comment: function in C# for determining the currently installed software ... Where that function will retrieve information from?... Registry

Comment: Any reason why you don't followup on your questions or accept answers sreeee?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this through WMI: the class you need is `Win32_Product`.

It's *really* easy in Powershell:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product
```

will get the list of installed products, which you can then filter.

In C#, try the `System.Management` namespace:

```
    public bool CheckForMySQLServer()
    {
        string query = "SELECT Name FROM Win32_Product WHERE Name LIKE '%MySQL Server%'";

        var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
        var collection = searcher.Get();

        return collection.Count > 0;
    }
```

Note that this is hideously slow - takes over a minute on my PC - but you can get hold of the version number string if you need (see the `GetText()` method on the collection items).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you also need to access MySQL (a.o.t. just knowing about its presence) you could

- (Optional) load GAC copy of MySQL connector via reflection in a try-catch block, if that fails
- load local copy of MySQL connector
- Try to connect to localhost with bad username/password
- Check error code. If this is "access denied" you have MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Check MySQL installation registry key:

```
bool IsMySqlInstalled()
{
   return Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\MySQL AB") != null;
}
```

MySQL details on what key is created can be found [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/windows-install-wizard.html), under 'Changes to the Registry' section:

> The MySQL Installation Wizard creates one Windows registry key in a
>   typical install situation, located in
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MySQL AB.